# How to use iterator to update element of 2D string vector

Tags: c++, vector

See this code. I need to change the value of a specific element in a 2D string vector using the iterator.  I can use for loop with an index to do this. but here what i need is directly use the iterator to refer the element. something like `(*ite)[0] = "new name"`
Any idea? I added full working code here for your convenience

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


string convertInt(int number)
{
   stringstream ss;
   ss << number;
   return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
    vector<vector<string>> studentList;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        vector<string> student;
        student.push_back("name-"+convertInt(i));
        student.push_back(convertInt(i+10));
        studentList.push_back(student);
    }
    vector<string> temp;
    for(vector<vector<string>>::iterator ite = studentList.begin(); ite != studentList.end(); ++ite){
        temp = *ite;
        if(temp[0].compare("name-5")==0){
            cout << "Changeing the name of student 5" << endl;
            // I need to change the studentList[5][0] (original value not the one in temp vector) at here using iterator ite
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: By the way, if you use C++11, `convertInt` could be replaced with `std::to_string`. Also, with `std::string`, you don't have to use `compare()`. You can safely check equality using `==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `temp = *ite` makes a copy of vector(*student*), if you modify on `temp`, it's not modified on real `studentList`, that's why you need `(*ite)[0] = "new name"` to change value on real element.

Using for loop is a bit "*ugly*", use [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) instead of for loop:

```
bool IsFindFifthName(const std::vector<std::string>& student)
{
   return student[0] == "name-5";
}

 std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>::iterator iter 
  = std::find_if(studentList.begin(), studentList.end(), IsFindFifthName);

if (iter != studentList.end() )
{
   (*iter)[0] = " new name";       
}
```

Or use Lambda if C++11 is available:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>::iterator iter 
  = std::find_if(studentList.begin(), studentList.end(), 
    [](std::vector<std::string>& student){ return student[0] == "name-5"; });

 if (iter != studentList.end() )
 {
    (*iter)[0] = " new name";       
 }
```

Comment: thank you so much for your solution. but why do you say first solution bit ugly (is that not following best practice? )?. In you second solution, is there any way to define `IsFindFifthName` at the location. otherwise, It need to declare as a new function. that is an extra burden.

Comment: yeah, that's why ppl love lumbda. Also is  good to learn all STL algorithms, they make code clear and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Using STL algorithm Transform in case could a good option. The algorithm internally uses iterators. A Sample example:

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> VectorOfString;
void DisplayStudent(const std::vector<VectorOfString>& StudentList)
{
    std::for_each(StudentList.cbegin(), StudentList.cend(), 
        [](const VectorOfString& vectorElement)
    {
        std::for_each(vectorElement.cbegin(), vectorElement.cend(), 
            [](const std::string& value)
        {
            std::cout << value << endl;
        });     
    });
}

std::vector<VectorOfString> StudentList;

std::string data1 = "One";
std::string data2 = "Two";

VectorOfString data(2);
data.push_back(data1);
data.push_back(data2);

StudentList.push_back(data);



DisplayStudent(StudentList);

std::for_each(std::begin(StudentList), std::end(StudentList), 
    [](VectorOfString& vectorElement)
{
    std::transform(std::begin(vectorElement), std::end(vectorElement), std::begin(vectorElement),
        [](std::string& value)-> std::string
    {
        if(value.compare("One") == 0)
            return "OneOne";
        else
            return value;
    });     
});

DisplayStudent(StudentList);
```